# CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action,bool>'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to write a script and get a Google sign in for a unity android based SSO to get users to create account on my game.
I am getting the error `"CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action,bool>'"` on one of the code snips I got from the developer sites from google.
https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/README.md?fbclid=IwAR2bIbeEOcwm193e8aL3I9GwqdWoczYR1oNY7jfvCDFnt4Vepu0QfSULctM#sign-in

`Social.localUser.Authenticate(ProcessAuthentication);` this line has that error being thrown.

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using UnityEngine;
    using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
    using GooglePlayGames;
    using System;
    using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
    using UnityEngine.Events;

    public class GoogleManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private bool ;
        public void Start()
        {
           PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
           Social.localUser.Authenticate(ProcessAuthentication);
        }

    internal void ProcessAuthentication(SignInStatus status)
    {
        if (status == SignInStatus.Success)
        {
            // Continue with Play Games Services
        }
        else
        {
            // Disable your integration with Play Games Services or show a login button
            // to ask users to sign-in. Clicking it should call
            PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ManuallyAuthenticate(ProcessAuthentication);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help here would be awesome.

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using UnityEngine;
    using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;
    using GooglePlayGames;
    using System;
    using UnityEngine.SocialPlatforms;
    using UnityEngine.Events;

    public class GoogleManager : MonoBehaviour
    {
    public Text m_Message;
    public Button m_SignIn;
    private UnityAction SignInGooglePlayGames;
    private Action<bool> OnGoogleLogin;
    private bool success;

    private void Awake()
    {
        InitializePlayGamesLogin();
    }
    private void Start()
    {
        PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
        .AddOauthScope("profile")
        .RequestServerAuthCode(false)
        .Build();
        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);

        // recommended for debugging:
        PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;

        // Activate the Google Play Games platform
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
        m_SignIn.onClick.RemoveAllListeners();
        m_SignIn.onClick.AddListener(SignInGooglePlayGames);
    }
    void InitializePlayGamesLogin()
    {
        var config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
            // Requests an ID token be generated.  
            // This OAuth token can be used to
            // identify the player to other services such as Firebase.
            .RequestIdToken()
            .Build();

        PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
        PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
        PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();
    }

    public void LoginGoogle()
    {
        
        
        Social.localUser.Authenticate(OnGoogleLogin);
        if (success)
        {
            // Call Unity Authentication SDK to sign in or link with Google.
            Debug.Log("Login with Google done. IdToken: " + ((PlayGamesLocalUser)Social.localUser).GetIdToken());
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Unsuccessful login");
        }
    }

}
```

Or has anyone set up google play log in that can help me out

Thanks

Comment: You do know the line you have listed here was part of a comment -- not the code that you should call on the line.  THAT CODE IS 100% WRONG based on what it says above.  Please read the comment and do what it says

Comment: This code doesn’t represent the example. What is “Social”? Whatever it is I’m guessing it’s localUser.Authentication uses different requirements than the one listed

Comment: the second batch of code is what i used before and with that again i got nothing.

Comment: What version of GPGS are you using? 10.14? 11.01?

Comment: `cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Action<bool>`  "method group" is a collection of methods with the same name. The compiler cant implicitly create the required action type, because none (or too many) of the methods in the group match the required delegate signature. You need to check the actual argument type, and probably construct an explicit matching delegate.